# Unable to install any .pkg file after reinstalling Ventura - Installer crashes

Tags: install, crash, pkg

Hoping someone can help. My Mac auto-updated to Sonoma when it released. As that caused a load of problems with the apps I use, I've wiped my hard drive, reinstalled Ventura and restored my files from a Time Machine backup. All seemed well but I've been trying to install a number of .pkg files and every single time without fail, the installer crashes and gives the following error log:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 84CBD041-8F12-483A-BCEC-9219EC1DBE92
CrashReporter Key:   227EF547-8608-5873-6E4E-10F36A9FBE2A
Hardware Model:      Mac13,1
Process:             Installer [4325]
Path:                /System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer
Identifier:          com.apple.installer
Version:             6.2.0 (1131)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.apple.installer [1075]

Date/Time:           2023-10-03 23:47:58.7952 +0100
Launch Time:         2023-10-03 23:47:58.2238 +0100
OS Version:          macOS 13.6 (22G120)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000020
VM Region Info: 0x20 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 140703124500448
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)   7ff7ffc13000-7ff7ffc16000 [   12K] r--/r-- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [4325]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   runtime                             0x7ff7ffbd204c 0x7ff7ffbce000 + 16460


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000022   x1: 0x0000000000000020   x2: 0x00007ff7ffbf19d0   x3: 0x0000000000000002
    x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x00007ff7ffbfa983   x6: 0x0000000000000020   x7: 0x00007ff7ffbfa97c
    x8: 0xfa19adc40a4300d8   x9: 0xfa19adc40a4300d8  x10: 0x00007ff7ffbffb99  x11: 0x00007ff7ffbffb99
   x12: 0x0000000000000078  x13: 0x000000000000001e  x14: 0x00007ff7ffbf1980  x15: 0x00007ff7ffbffb11
   x16: 0x00007ff7ffbffb12  x17: 0x0000000308875a67  x18: 0x000000030887602b  x19: 0x00007ff7ffbffb11
   x20: 0x0000000000000022  x21: 0x00007ff7ffbfff11  x22: 0x00007ff7ffbf9ddf  x23: 0x0000000308875b90
   x24: 0x000000010a3c82e0  x25: 0x0000000000000248  x26: 0x0000000000000009  x27: 0x00000002024b1000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x0000000308875a90   lr: 0x00007ff7ffbebb7c
    sp: 0x0000000308875a90   pc: 0x00007ff7ffbd204c cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0x0000000000000020  esr: 0x92000005 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x202409000 -        0x2024a4fff dyld (*) <3df96f32-b9c9-3566-a6b7-4daebc6d6563> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7ff7ffbce000 -     0x7ff7ffbfdfff runtime (*) <15ccd9bf-9a15-3540-a1ff-3abea3e2ca9d> /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

EOF

-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"Installer","timestamp":"2023-10-03 23:47:58.00 +0100","app_version":"6.2.0","slice_uuid":"1e8351c1-18eb-303b-9896-0eceb74c162e","build_version":"1131","platform":0,"bundleID":"com.apple.installer","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":1,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 13.6 (22G120)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Installer","incident_id":"84CBD041-8F12-483A-BCEC-9219EC1DBE92"}
{
  "uptime" : 970,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 502,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "Mac13,1",
  "coalitionID" : 1075,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 13.6",
    "build" : "22G120",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-10-03 23:47:58.7952 +0100",
  "incident" : "84CBD041-8F12-483A-BCEC-9219EC1DBE92",
  "pid" : 4325,
  "translated" : true,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-10-03 23:47:58.2238 +0100",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 23439130194,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 23452676189,
  "procName" : "Installer",
  "procPath" : "\/System\/Library\/CoreServices\/Installer.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/Installer",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"6.2.0","CFBundleVersion":"1131","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.installer"},
  "buildInfo" : {"ProjectName":"Installer","SourceVersion":"1131000000000000","BuildVersion":"1368"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"0C9FB9E4-CA6A-570F-B5A1-7ED200CEB22F"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.installer",
  "crashReporterKey" : "227EF547-8608-5873-6E4E-10F36A9FBE2A",
  "codeSigningID" : "com.apple.installer",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570522369,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 1,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 0,
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "vmRegionInfo" : "0x20 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 140703124500448\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  \n      VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)   7ff7ffc13000-7ff7ffc16000 [   12K] r--\/r-- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000020","rawCodes":[1,32],"type":"EXC_BAD_ACCESS","signal":"SIGSEGV","subtype":"KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":11,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Segmentation fault: 11","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":4325},
  "vmregioninfo" : "0x20 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 140703124500448\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  \n      VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)   7ff7ffc13000-7ff7ffc16000 [   12K] r--\/r-- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)",
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":48945,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":34},{"value":32},{"value":140703124363728},{"value":2},{"value":1},{"value":140703124400515},{"value":32},{"value":140703124400508},{"value":18021626441397108952},{"value":18021626441397108952},{"value":140703124421529},{"value":140703124421529},{"value":120},{"value":30},{"value":140703124363648},{"value":140703124421393},{"value":140703124421394},{"value":13027990119},{"value":13027991595},{"value":140703124421393},{"value":34},{"value":140703124422417},{"value":140703124397535},{"value":13027990416},{"value":4466705120},{"value":584},{"value":9},{"value":8628408320,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"dyld_all_image_infos"},{"value":1}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":140703124339580},"cpsr":{"value":1610616832},"fp":{"value":13027990160},"sp":{"value":13027990160},"esr":{"value":2449473541,"description":"(Data Abort) byte read Translation fault"},"pc":{"value":140703124234316,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":32}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":16460,"imageIndex":1}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 8627720192,
    "size" : 638976,
    "uuid" : "3df96f32-b9c9-3566-a6b7-4daebc6d6563",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 140703124217856,
    "size" : 196608,
    "uuid" : "15ccd9bf-9a15-3540-a1ff-3abea3e2ca9d",
    "path" : "\/usr\/libexec\/rosetta\/runtime",
    "name" : "runtime"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
],
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1168K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1168K(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=136.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=136.1M(100%)\n\n                                   VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                           SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                        =======  ======= \nRosetta Generic                         8K        2 \nRosetta IndirectBranch (reserved)      32K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nRosetta JIT                         128.0M        1 \nSTACK GUARD                          56.0M        1 \nStack                                8176K        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE (reserved)                 12K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\n__DATA                                 80K        3 \n__DATA_CONST                           32K        1 \n__DATA_DIRTY                           16K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                            368K        4 \n__TEXT                                816K        2 \nmapped file                           676K        7 \n===========                        =======  ======= \nTOTAL                               194.0M       26 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space      193.9M       26 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "4ea3f1ca5c2fb439a2d0e5b254b3a83431390b25",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [

  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
},
  "reportNotes" : [
  "dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed"
]
}

Model: Mac13,1, BootROM 10151.40.132, proc 10:8:2 processors, 32 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Apple M1 Max, Apple M1 Max, Built-In
Display: C27F591, 1920 x 1080 (1080p FHD - Full High Definition), Main, MirrorOff, Online
Display: HDMI, 1920 x 1080 (1080p FHD - Full High Definition), MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: LPDDR5, Samsung
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi (0x14E4, 0x4387), wl0: May 27 2023 02:14:41 version 20.96.31.0.8.7.148 FWID 01-1f7d4484
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: PSSD T7
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: iLok
USB Device: USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB2 Hub
USB Device: USB3 Gen2 Hub
USB Device: Elements 25A3
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Studio, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Studio, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Studio, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Studio, Apple Inc.
```

I can't make any sense of it at all. Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by reinstalling Rosetta via Terminal!